# jQuery Slideshow: How to remove fancy effects?

Tags: jquery

I am using the slideshow from this page:
http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/imagestrip/imageslide-plugin.html

It does just what I need (big main picture with list of numbers to see other pics, easy to style) but I do not need/want the slidey effect that it's got going on.  I just want to click the number and have the picture change without any effects.

What lines do I need to edit/remove from the jquery.slideviewer.js so that it just shows the image without any fancy sliding?

(Or, alternatively, have you seen a better solution out there?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gah, I can't believe I just spent two days trying to wrap my head around other people's js code, when all along the perfect solution was just sitting there at the top of the Google results:

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Totally simple and perfect.  In the "Intermediate demo part 2" it shows how one can add a the very simple attribute "pager" to the function call and VOILA a numbered pager that is easy to understand and style and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Link here to an example of a simple image switcher, this is slightly different from what you want in that it has the images in a list to pick from.. but that is easily changed.

http://www.creativewebspecialist.co.uk/jQuery_examples/image-switcher/index.html#